# Constraining a derived variable of a type class or an instance

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a type class for my `pipes` library to define an abstract interface to `Proxy`-like types.  The type class looks something like:

```
class ProxyC p where
    idT   :: (Monad m) => b' -> p a' a b' b m r
    (<-<) :: (Monad m)
          => (c' -> p b' b c' c m r)
          -> (b' -> p a' a b' b m r)
          -> (c' -> p a' a c' c m r)
    ... -- other methods
```

I'm also writing extensions for the `Proxy` type that are of the form:

```
instance (ProxyC p) => ProxyC (SomeExtension p) where ....
```

... and I'd like these instances to be able to impose an additional constraint that if `m` is a `Monad` then `p a' a b' b m` is a `Monad` for all `a'`, `a`, `b'`, and `b`.

However, I have no clue how to cleanly encode that as a constraint either for the `ProxyC` class or for the instances.  The only solution I currently know of is to do something like encoding it in the method signatures of the class:

```
    (<-<) :: (Monad m, Monad (p b' b c' c m), Monad (p a' a b' b m))
          => (c' -> p b' b c' c m r)
          -> (b' -> p a' a b' b m r)
          -> (c' -> p a' a c' c m r)
```

... but I was hoping there would be a simpler and more elegant solution.

**Edit**: And not even that last solution works, since the compiler does not deduce that `(Monad (SomeExtension p a' a b' b m))` implies `(Monad (p a' a b' b m))` for a specific choice of variables, even when given the following instance:

```
instance (Monad (p a b m)) => Monad (SomeExtension p a b m) where ...
```

**Edit #2**: The next solution I'm considering is just duplicating the methods for the `Monad` class within the `ProxyC` class:

```
class ProxyC p where
    return' :: (Monad m) => r -> p a' a b' b m r
    (!>=) :: (Monad m) => ...
```

... and then instantiating them with each `ProxyC` instance.  This seems okay for my purposes since the `Monad` methods only need to be used internally for extension writing and the original type still has a proper `Monad` instance for the downstream user.  All this does is just expose the `Monad` methods to the instance writer.

Comment: AFAIK you can only do it with ugly hacks, like f.e. Edward Kmett does in http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/constraints/0.3.2/doc/html/Data-Constraint-Forall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a rather trivial way to do this is use a GADT to move the proof to the value level

```
data IsMonad m where
  IsMonad :: Monad m => IsMonad m 

class ProxyC p where
  getProxyMonad :: Monad m => IsMonad (p a' a b' b m)
```

you will need to explicitly open the dictionary wherever you need it

```
--help avoid type signatures
monadOf :: IsMonad m -> m a -> IsMonad m
monadOf = const

--later on
case getProxyMonad `monadOf` ... of
  IsMonad -> ...
```

the tactic of using GADTs to pass proofs of propositions is really very general.  If you are okay using constraint kinds, and not just GADTs, you can instead use Edward Kmett's `Data.Constraint` package

```
class ProxyC p where
  getProxyMonad :: Monad m => Dict (Monad (p a' a b' b m))
```

which lets you defined

```
getProxyMonad' :: ProxyC p => (Monad m) :- (Monad (p a' a b' b m))
getProxyMonad' = Sub getProxyMonad
```

and then use a fancy infix operator to tell the compiler where to look for the monad instance

```
 ... \\ getProxyMonad'
```

in fact, the `:-` entailment type forms a category (where the objects are constraints), and this category has *lots* of nice structure, which is to say it is pretty nice to do proofs with.

p.s. none of these snippets are tested.

edit: 
you could also combine the value level proofs with a newtype wrapper and not need to open GADTs all over the place

```
newtype WrapP p a' a b' b m r = WrapP {unWrapP :: p a' a b' b m r}

instance ProxyC p => Monad (WrapP p) where
  return = case getProxyMonad of
                Dict -> WrapP . return
  (>>=) = case getProxyMonad of
               Dict -> \m f -> WrapP $ (unWrapP m) >>= (unWrapP . f)

instance ProxyC p => ProxyC (WrapP p) where
  ...
```

I suspect, but obviously have not tested, that this implementation will also be relatively efficient.

Comment: I guess my only concern about this is how much overhead there is for wrapping and unwrapping the `data` type.  Remember that I'd be doing such a round trip on every bind.  However, I haven't benchmarked it, so it is pure speculation on my part.  Right now I have another solution that looks something like: `newtype P p a' a b' b m r = P (p a' a b' b m r)` and then I write `instance (ProxyC p, Monad m) => Monad (P p a' a b' b m) where ...`, and I change all the `ProxyC` methods to have `P` in their signature.

Comment: The Dictionary reification trick did work, although I ended up using Edward's `constraint` package to do it.